# Retrieve Data of an employee for last month/period

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in sql server table where I store the month and year for the employees in varchar datatype... like Jan-2016.

Now I am trying to retrieve data from table for a particular employee for last month (with format month-year) i.e. Jan-2016 among the multiple months.

please suggest me the sql query for the task?????????

Comment: For previous months relative to current month or last month employee has been worked?

Answer (score 1):

```
--As last month value is static, so lets store it in variable and then use it in where clause.
declare @LastMonth varchar(8)
SET @LastMonth = replace(right(convert(varchar(100), 
                                       dateadd(mm, -1, getdate()), 
                                       106)
                              , 8), ' ', '-'
                        )

select * from myTable
where dateCol =  @LastMonth
```